# looping using .loc and passing condition in if

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing 2 columns - `len` and `agr`. Here is the data:
[dummy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBDC2.png).

I want to slice some part from `agr` if value of `len` is 7. Here is the snippet for the same:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    print (i)

    if df.loc(i,'len')==7:
        print ("if",i)
        df['agr1'] = df.agr.str.slice(3,5)
        df['agr2'] = df.agr.str.slice(1,2)    
    else:
        print ("else",i)
        df['agr1'] = df.agr.str.slice(4)
        df['agrt2'] = df.agr.str.slice(3,6)
```

However I am getting error:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.
```

Comment: Please include dataframes in a format where I don't have to type them in by hand. Post the expected output. Include the full traceback of the error message. Do you accept a solution without loops?

Comment: In short, @timgeb is requesting a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Your TypeError is because `.loc` takes brackets, like `.loc[i, j]`, not `.loc(i, j)`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make new columns and fill them with nulls
df['agr1'] = np.nan
df['agr2'] = np.nan

# Find all the rows where len is 7
df_idx = df['len'] == 7 

# Set agr1 and agr2 where len is 7 
df.loc[df_idx, 'agr1'] = df.loc[df_idx, 'agr'].str.slice(4)
df.loc[df_idx, 'agr2'] = df.loc[df_idx, 'agr'].str.slice(3,6)

# Set agr1 and agr2 where len isn't 7
df.loc[~df_idx, 'agr1'] = df.loc[~df_idx, 'agr'].str.slice(3,5)
df.loc[`df_idx, 'agr2'] = df.loc[~df_idx, 'agr'].str.slice(1,2)
```

As always, without any data I have no idea if this is what you'd like to do or if it's wrong (or broken).

Comment: Using square bracket [], as you mentioned answer my question :). Also I had attached dummy data. Does  it not gives the idea about the data. I am sorry. I am very new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @yashul It's not a problem, it's mostly a disclaimer that I can't promise that the code provided will work or do what it's supposed to (so check it if you use it)